# Alterar background de uma classe dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho um site onde a criação do conteúdo é dinâmica e o usuário pode escolher a cor a ser utilizada em componentes, mas, preciso que ele veja a atualização em tempo real, então, preciso que a classe seja alterada com o valor necessário e que os elementos adicionados também ganhem essa alteração.

Tenho uma classe no meu CSS da seguinte maneira:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .color
    {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

Como alterar o `background` dessa classe dinamicamente para que todos os elementos recebam o novo valor do `background` e os próximos elementos a serem criados já venham com esse elemento?

Comment: Explique melhor o que você está tentando fazer, porque não está claro.

Comment: Tenho um site onde a criação do conteúdo é dinamica e o usuario pode escolher a cor a ser utilizada em componentes, mas, preciso que ele veja a atualização em tempo real, então, preciso que a classe seja alterada com o valor necessário e que os elementos adicionados também ganhem essa alteração

Comment: Caio, editei minha resposta, veja se essa solução serve.

Comment: não da @PauloMaciel mas a do Sergio é exatamente o que eu precisava :D

Comment: Removi a solução que eu havia colocado já que não está alterando os elementos futuros, mas adicionei um complemento a resposta de Sergio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você tiver o CSS dentro do HTML pode fazer assim:

```
var style = $('style').text();
var newStyle = '.color {color: red; }';
$('style').text(newStyle);
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/7CT8q/)

O seletor `$('style')` vai procurar o `<style>` e mudar-lhe o conteúdo. Atenção que este método pode ser "força bruta", por isso sugiro ter somente o minimo necessário no HTML

Comment: isso resolveu o meu problema, valeu :D

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando a resposta de Sergio, caso você não utilize a tag `style` no seu HTML, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
if($('style').length){
    var style = $('style').text();
    var newStyle = '.color {color: red; }';
    $('style').text(newStyle);
}else{
    $( "<style>.color {background-color : red}</style>" ).appendTo( "head" )
}
```

Assim você pode colocar seu `CSS` inicial separado do seu HTML.