# Como alterar background-image do site dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

Então, queria fazer um bg-image se alterar dinamicamente igual nesse exemplo: http://www.goesenlinea.com/agus/

O background muda a cada 5 segundos.

Alguém sabe como ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer via JavaScript com um timer rodando de 5 em 5 seg. Vide exemplo:

```
// initial call, or just call refresh directly
setInterval(AsyncTrocaImg, 5000);


function AsyncTrocaImg() {
    $.post(base + "Home/GetNewImg", {}, function (URL) {
         $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+URL+')');
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("error");
    })
}
```

Mas tome cuidado com as imagens, para que seu site não fique "pesado".

Teria também algumas outras formas até simples, mas esta é a forma que eu faria.

Veja também se estes links te ajudam:

[CSS vários backgrounds](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10627/css-v%C3%A1rios-backgrounds?rq=1)

[Alterar background de uma classe dinamicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15128/alterar-background-de-uma-classe-dinamicamente?rq=1)